# Explain how this javascript codes sums two numbers and those between them

Tags: javascript, loops

I'm taking javascript lessons and I'm currently doing some little projects.

One project is this:
*Given two integers, which can be positive and negative, find the sum of all the numbers between including them too and return it. If both numbers are equal return a or b.*

One of the solutions I've found is this :

```
function GetSum(a, b) {
    if(a == b) {
        return a
    }
    else if (a < b) {
        return a + GetSum(a+1, b)
    } else {
        return a + GetSum(a-1, b)
    };
}
console.log(GetSum(-1, 2));
```

Please, I would like an explanation on why the code works.

...and, I will like to know why the code below is always returning 0

```
function GetSum(a, b) {
    let lower, higher;
    let result = 0;
    //return either of it if they are equal
    if(a == b) {
        return a;
    } else {
        if(a > b) {
            higher = a;
            lower = b;
        } else {
            higher = b;
            lower = a;
        }
        for(i = lower; i <= higher; i++) {
            result += i;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
console.log(GetSum(3, 9))
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Has your course gone through recursion? That's for the first (working) example.

Comment: Your second code outputs `42`, not `0`. That's still not the sum, but I can see *why* it is outputting that.

Comment: No it works fine. It even returns the [ultimate answer to life, the universe and everything](http://jsbin.com/hojaqururu/edit?console)

Comment: Actually, the sum is 42. Ends are inclusive.

Comment: @ObsidianAge My bad, that means the code works.. It sums the numbers and those between them.

I made a typo on the text editor on my PC but while typing it here. I corrected the typo,  that's why it works. 
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

We can simplify the code to this:

```
function getSum( a,b ){
   if (a == b) return a; //(1)
   if (a < b) {
      return a + getSum(a+1, b); //(2)
   }else {
      return a + getSum(a-1,b); //(3)
   }
}

getSum(1,3)
```

So at the first function call a is 1 and b is 3 so it goes into branch 2:

```
return 1 +  getSum(1 + 1, 3)
```

So now getSum is called from inside getSum, thats called recursion. Now getSum goes into branch 2 again and does

```
 return 2 + getSum(2 + 1, 3)
```

As now a equals b, getSum now goes into branch 1 and returns a (3). If we summarize the three lines above

```
 getSum(1,3)
 1 + getSum(2,3)
 1 + ( 2 + getSum(3,3))
 1 + ( 2 + (3))
```

---

The whole thing as a oneliner:

```
 const getSum = (a, b) => a === b ? a : getSum(a + (a < b)?1:-1, b);
```

Or using a loop:

```
 const getSum = (a, b) => {
   const res = 0;
   if(b < a) [a,b] = [b,a];
   while(a <= b) res += a++;
   return res;
}
```

or using tricky math:

```
const getSum = (a, b) => 1/2 * Math.abs((a ** 2 + a - b ** 2 - b));
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. You really made me understand what goes on in a recursion. 

I must admit I was completely lost from the "one liner" point onward

...but the recursion explanation is great